# How to show radio button when click on spinner in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, arraylist, android-spinner

I am working on an android project i want to show spinner data with radio button please suggest how can i do this. This is my code

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sMonth);
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
ArrayList categories=new ArrayList();
categories.add("Month");
categories.add("Jan");
categories.add("Feb");
categories.add("Mar");
categories.add("Apr");
categories.add("May");
categories.add("Jun");
categories.add("Jul");
categories.add("Aug");
categories.add("Sep");
categories.add("Oct");
categories.add("Nov");
categories.add("Dec");
ArrayAdapter dataAdapter=new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,categories);
dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

Comment: create custom layout for it instead of default one

Answer (score 15):

you just need to add android layout `select_dialog_singlechoice` on dropdown in spinner adaptor like:..

```
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice);
```

Comment: This is the perfect answer.  In older versions of Android, the radio button was part of `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item`, but it isn't any longer.  `android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice` is the answer.  And for those who are using custom layouts, just add `android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"` and `android:gravity="center_vertical"` (which makes the radio button align with the text).

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyAndroidAppActivity extends Activity {

  private Spinner spinner1, spinner2;
  private Button btnSubmit;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

addItemsOnSpinner2();
addListenerOnButton();
addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection();
  }

  // add items into spinner dynamically
  public void addItemsOnSpinner2() {

    spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("list 1");
    list.add("list 2");
    list.add("list 3");
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner2.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
  }

  public void addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection() {
    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new CustomOnItemSelectedListener());
  }

  // get the selected dropdown list value
  public void addListenerOnButton() {

    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    btnSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);

    btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {


      }

    });
  }
}
```

//CustomOnItemSelectedListener.java

```
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CustomOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener    {

      public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,long id) {

  }

  @Override
   public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  }

}
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Spinner
       android:id="@+id/spinner1"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:entries="@array/country_arrays"
       android:prompt="@string/country_prompt" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSubmit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Submit" />

</LinearLayout>
```

//string.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">Yourapp</string>
    <string name="country_prompt">Choose a country</string>

    <string-array name="country_arrays">
        <item>Malaysia</item>
        <item>United States</item>
        <item>Indonesia</item>

    </string-array>

</resources>
```